# What is the name of phenomenon that people state their initial opinion more firmly after discussion in group polarization?

Tags: social-psychology

In reading "[group polarization](https://psychologenie.com/concept-of-group-polarization-in-psychology-explained)", "

> that a person tends to shift to a more extreme opinion when in a group
> setting than what his/her original opinion might have been"

So, in the case that people change their opinion and follow the main dominated opinion of the group is called "Normative Influence" or "Informational Influence". However, I did not see the name of the phenomenon that the person state their opinion more firmly after the group discussion. Example from the link above

> To state an example, let’s say that a person thinks that child beauty
> pageants―contest featuring under-age children―are not a very good
> idea. This opinion that he/she harbors could be a very mild one, where
> she might not really have given it a lot of thought. However, if she’s
> placed in a group and this topic is taken up for discussion, there is
> a very high possibility that by the end of the discussion, she will
> not only be completely against child beauty pageants, but she may
> begin stating this opinion more firmly, and maybe, even join a protest
> group.

Comment: I'm kind of confused ... I thought this *was* group polarization...  What is the difference between your question and the quoted definition of group polarization?  "phenomenon that people state their initial opinion more firmly after discussion in group" sounds the same to me as "a person tends to shift to a more extreme opinion when in a group setting" ... What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg. Thank you for your suggestion. From my understanding, "group polarization" means that people go extreme after joining a group discussion, either confirming their initial idea or be convinced by opposed idea. The latter has the specific name is "normative influence" or "informative influence". I am trying to find the specific term for that "People more firmly state their opinion after group discussion"

Comment: What I am looking for is the term for the phenomenon that people go further extreme in their initial opinion, "group polarization" is a general word, not a specific enough for each phenomenon.

Comment: Oh, so when you said "change their opinion", you meant specifically "convinced by opposed idea"?  However, in the article you linked to, "change their opinion" means "shift to a more extreme opinion", and not "change to opposite opinion."  The article also explains that normative and informative influences are the cause of opinion change (however you want to define it).  I think the term you are looking for really is group polarization, or perhaps [attitude polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_polarization#Attitude_polarization).

Comment: I got it, thanks @ArnonWeinberg, "attitude polarization" seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: "**normative and informative influences are the cause of opinion change**" I think it should be "**normative and informative influences are the cause of being convinced by opposite opinion**"?

Comment: Like I said, however you want to define it.  Normative and informative influences are the cause of change to opposite opinion *and* change to more extreme opinion.  Anyway, glad you found what you are looking for.  Closing as [answered in comments](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2163/7001).